# React Native - FlatList make get request for each item in renderItems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, axios

I want to make a `get` request for each item in my `renderItems()` so I make it like this:

```
renderItems({ item }) {
  axios.get(Utilities.url + "Symbol/" + item.Id).then(response => {
    let eachItem = response.data;
  });

  console.log(eachItem);

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "flex-end",
        alignSelf: "stretch",
        marginRight: 2
      }}
    >
      <Text
        style={{
          color: Colors.WHITE,
          fontSize: 16
        }}
      >
        {eachItem.LVal18AFC}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

But I get the error for:

> ReferenceError: eachItem is not defined

I tried to convert the `renderItems` to an `async` function and use `await` but I get another error!

Any solution...?

### UPDATE

I used `var eachItem = []` outside the axios' then function but now I'm getting:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'LVal18AFC' of undefined!

Comment: Put `let eachItem` outside `axios` first, you are not in same scope.

Comment: I use `var` outside the function but now I'm getting error for `Cannot read property 'InsCode' of undefined!

Comment: Hey, are you making this call inside your render function?
You cannot make async calls inside the render function.

Comment: @YashKalwani - No! the items are dynamic so I have to make request for each!

Comment: The question says FlatList makes get request. Your FlatList has to be inside the render function. And the FlatList makes the async call. Hence, you are making a async call inside the `render` of your class which won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you did a bad practice in calling API, what I suggest is, create a separate component for each row you want to display and inside a row call an API you want

so according to your code

```
class Row extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            eachItem: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { item } = this.props;
        axios.get(Utilities.url + "Symbol/" + item.Id).then(response => {
            this.setState({eachItem: response.data});
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "flex-end",
                    alignSelf: "stretch",
                    marginRight: 2
                }}
            >
                <Text
                    style={{
                        color: Colors.WHITE,
                        fontSize: 16
                    }}
                >
                    {this.state.eachItem ? this.state.eachItem.LVal18AFC : null}
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great but I get `Unable to find node on an unmounted component` then when i click dismiss, I get my data and it's ok! How can I solve this error?

Comment: this is not in a scope of this question, may be something else is wrong

Comment: When i comment this part, everything is ok so I guess the problem is related to this...

Comment: then sorry no idea, I just wrote a code to explain you only

Comment: Thanks - I will find a solution for that and make an update in my question then!

Comment: Not really sure but i think you can't render null in JSX, render the entire `<View>` conditionally i.e `{ this.state.eachItem ? <View> <Text>{this.state.eachItem}</Text></View> } : <View />`

Comment: you can render null in jsx

Answer (score 4):

@Jigar is correct.
Why it is not working:
When you call the `renderItems` function js looks at the asyn call and puts it into its event loop for execution later. It then moves on and logs to your console `eachItem` which is undefined right now. Then renders your JSX and then executes the async call ( i.e axios request ) when the request serves the data back it is simply store in `eachItem` which is in the scope of the axios function.

Answer (score 2):

This is a scoping issue. Using the `let` keyword in the function passed to your `GET` promise, means it's only accessible inside that function.

I'd actually suggest abstracting things into a component, which will manage its own respective axios call. Something like this:

```
class Item {
  componentWillMount(props) {
    axios.get(Utilities.url + "Symbol/" + props.Id).then(response => {
      this.setState({
        data: {
          ...this.state.data,
          ...response.data,
      })
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.data) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "flex-end",
          alignSelf: "stretch",
          marginRight: 2
        }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{
            color: Colors.WHITE,
            fontSize: 16
          }}
        >
          { this.state.data.id }
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function Parent(props) {
  <FlatList renderItem={ ({ item }) => <Item id={ item.id } /> } />
}
```

Comment: I use `var` outside the function but now I'm getting error for `Cannot read property 'InsCode' of undefined!

Comment: Thanks - but I get Unable to find node on an unmounted component then when i click dismiss, I get my data and it's ok! How can I solve this error?

Comment: ah, probably want to be using componentDidMount instead of WillMount